# Styling checkboxGroupButtons label in rShiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to unbold the label for a checkboxGroupButtons in rShiny. I've tried using HTML, which works for italicizing, but the default is still bold text.

```
output$indicSelectgraph <- renderUI(checkboxGroupButtons( "indicGraph", label = HTML("<b>Select Indicator(s)</b> <i>(min. 1)</i>"), choices=c(unique(dataset$Indicator))))
```

The result is:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O3cT.png)

I thought maybe I could just add a fluidRow line to paste a label above it, then leave the label blank but it did not work:

```
  fluidRow(HTML("Select Indicator(s)"), 
                style = "font-weight:bold")
       fluidRow(HTML("<i>(min 1.)</i>")), 
               style = "font-weight:100")
output$indicSelectgraph <- renderUI(checkboxGroupButtons( "indicGraph", choices=c(unique(dataset$Indicator))))
```

Anyone have solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CSS to do this.
Check here several ways to add CSS to a shiny app : [Using custom CSS in your app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html)

To modify elements inside of an input (or any other Shiny element), you need to identify the CSS div or class you want to alter. To do so, you can use the navigator inspector on your shiny app (CTRL+SHIFT+I or right click -> inspect), and search the HTML and CSS code to find your element. Then, you can try several modifications directly in the inspector, and copy paste them into your shiny code.

If you want to alter all of the inputs of your page, you can alter the CSS of the class of your object. If you want to alter only one, you need to alter the CSS id of your object. Most of the time in Shiny, it is the inputId.

So here you want to alter the label of the Input "indicGraph". So you need to modify the CSS of the object `#indicGraph-label`. It is **not** always written like this (inputId-element), so checking the inspector of your browser will be very helpful.

And just above, to remove the bold effect on the label, I add the CSS property `font-weight` back to `normal`. By default it was 700 (bold).

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML("
  #indicGraph-label {
    font-weight: normal;
    }
  ")),
  uiOutput('indicSelectgraph')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$indicSelectgraph <- renderUI(
    checkboxGroupButtons(
      "indicGraph", 
      label = 'Select Indicator',
      choices=c('a', 'b'))
    )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```